# Python unit test assertEqual throwing assertionError in one machine but not in others

Tags: python, django, types, graphql

I've built a test case for a GraphQL mutation where I save inputs (priceOne and priceTwo) of type graphene.Decimal() into the model MyObj fields of type models.DecimalField and I return MyObj in the response.

The code below returns OK, test successful on my machine, let's call Machine A, and it also works on Machine B, but doesn't work on Machine C.

- Machine A: Windows 10, python 3.7 => OK
- Machine B: Ubuntu, python 3.8.0 => OK
- Machine C: Ubuntu, python 3.8.5 => F

Graphene - GraphQL

```
graphene==2.1.8
graphene-django==2.13.0
graphql-core==2.3.2
graphql-relay==2.0.1
```

```py
import json

from graphene_django.utils import GraphQLTestCase
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

from core.schema import schema
from my_app.models import MyObj


MY_MUTATION = '''
    mutation MyMutation($input: MyInput!) {
        myMutation(input: $input) {
            success
            myObj {
                id
                price
            }
        }
    }
'''


class TestMyMutation(GraphQLTestCase):
    GRAPHQL_SCHEMA = schema

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_obj = mixer.blend(MyObj)

        self.input_data = {
            'id': self.my_obj.id,
            'priceOne': '2000.00',
            'priceTwo': '0.10',
        }

    def test_my_mutation_success(self):

        response = self.query(MY_MUTATION, input_data=self.input_data)
        content = json.loads(response.content)

        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
        self.assertTrue(content['data']['myMutation']['success'])
        self.assertEqual(content['data']['myMutation']['myObj']['priceOne'], 2000.00)
        self.assertEqual(content['data']['myMutation']['myObj']['priceTwo'], 0.10)
```

On Machine C, the left argument is string:

> self.assertEqual(content['data']['myMutation']['myObj']['priceTwo'], 0.10)
> AssertionError: '0.10'!= 0.1

But on Machine A, it is float:

> print(type(content['data']['myMutation']['myObj']['priceOne']))
> <class 'float'>

We fixed the issue by transforming both arguments of assertEqual to Decimal and adding '' to the argument on the right. Plus added a quantize to left argument of 0.10 check.

```py
self.assertEqual(Decimal(content['data']['myMutation']['myObj']['priceOne']), Decimal('2000.00'))
self.assertEqual(Decimal(content['data']['myMutation']['myObj']['priceTwo']).quantize(Decimal(10)**(-2)), Decimal('0.10'))
```

**Question:**
Why does the first option does not work on Machine C but works on the other two?